# I would like to add the uploadExtraData in bootstrap-fileinput

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-file-upload

I am using bootstrap-fileinput, I am able to upload the file successfully, But I also want to send some data like user details with file to the server. is there any option to add data?

My JavaScript Code:

```
$('#xlf').fileinput({
                showPreview: false,
                uploadUrl: 'MuUrl',
                allowedFileExtensions: ['csv'],
                browseClass: "btn btn-info",
                elErrorContainer: '#errorBlock',
                msgUploadEnd: "File Uploded Successfully",
                maxFileSize: 92160
            });
```

Comment: can you create fiddle example?

Answer (score 2):

Uploading additional data to the server is done with the `uploadExtraData`. This only works for asynchronous uploads. If you're uploading with form submission just add the additional data in hidden fields in your form to send to your server.

[Ajax submission](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#ajax-submission)

Here is the Asynch option.

```
     $('#xlf').fileinput({
            showPreview: false,
            uploadUrl: 'MuUrl',
            allowedFileExtensions: ['csv'],
            browseClass: "btn btn-info",
            elErrorContainer: '#errorBlock',
            msgUploadEnd: "File Uploded Successfully",
            maxFileSize: 92160,
            // this is where the magic happens
            uploadAsync: true,
            uploadExtraData:{
               userid:'12345',
               firstname:'Jesus',
               lastname:'Christ'
            },
        });
```

Hope that will help someone, even though the answer is soo super-late.